# max-width applied to three images is changing one differently

Tags: html, css, width

Trying to get the three images to all be responsive and the same size.

For some reason, this code is causing the third image to be smaller than the other two. Any idea why?

It's weird because when I remove the `max-width` from the `.side-content-image img` in the CSS the images are the same size. But as soon as it is applied the third one is smaller than the other two.

I eliminated, hopefully, extraneous code from this HTML. This is all in a container with a specific width.

code:

```css
.side-content-image {
  width: 35%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.side-content-image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-content">
  <div class="side-content-image">
    <img src="./resources/images/information-orientation.jpg" alt="God
            view of people walking on a path">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="side-content">
  <div class="side-content-image">
    <img src="./resources/images/information-campus.jpg" alt="room
            with people at tables and world map on a wall">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="side-content">
  <div class="side-content-image">
    <img src="./resources/images/information-guest-lecture.jpg" alt="old
            man with glasses looking off into the distance">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ee06wyzy/

So I'm guessing:

1) The images aspect ratio being different might cause some issues, also depending if any of the images are not big enough to fill in the container's size. Try using same image in all three places and see if the problem persists.

```
.side-content-image img  {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

2) The problem might be the `side-content-image` - `width: 35%`, three of them will add up to 105% which might force `side-content-image` divs to shrink down if the 3 divs are displayed inline.

Try this and see if it is fixed:

```
.side-content-image {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. Playing around with it in jsfiddle helped a solution appear. I hadn't used that before. 

So I figured out a solution to the problem, but I still don't understand what is causing it in the first place. So still some digging to be done. 

Turns out the code I deleted was the problem. So I added that back in.

The quick solution is commented out in the CSS. But why is this 'problem div' causing the image to shrink and the 'working div' isn't. They seem to have the same structure, just different content. 

[https://jsfiddle.net/dnurse10/2pptomvv/#&togetherjs=Nut6718hBG]

Comment: I'm glad if I could help ;)